# Модель базы данных.

Tags: oracle, postgresql, база-данных, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Не подскажите, а существует ли инструмент которой на основе существующей базы данных строит модель визуальную, со всеми ссылками..? Знаю что можно с помощью visual studio сделать это для  msssql. А есть ли что нибудь универсальное или хотя бы для баз Oracle, Postrgre, MySQL?

Comment: Вопрос, а причём здесь UML?

Comment: По-моему, UML-модели базы данных нет. Есть схема которую, как я понял, вам надо сделать.

Comment: Ну я подразумевал под uml - диаграммы.

Answer (score 3):

Для MySQL есть [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).
Для Oracle тоже можно использовать стандартную тулзу: [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html).

Comment: Спасибо.
Очень интересно есть ли для Oracle?

Comment: обновил коммент.

Comment: toad оказывается тоже  умеет) Круто) спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Toad умеет работать  и с Postgre и с Mssql и с Oracle  и с  mysql и умеет строить реверсивно Диаграммы. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

DbForge умеет  - просто "перетащить" БД и готова наглядная диаграмма со всеми связями. Более того, в этой же диаграмме можно редактировать БД.

Answer (score 0):

[PowerDesigner 16.1](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner).

Очень крутой инструмент. Работает со всеми распространенными БД.

Answer (score 0):

`CA ERwin Data Modeler`.